# How rotation video to portrait when custom camera app?

Tags: android

I custom a camera app:
I set camera display portrait as:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Camera display portrait Ok, But file result (Video) not display portrait . 
I try code:

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setRotation(90);         
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

But it not ok.

Why ? 
How fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to rotate the stream.

Comment: try my answer!!!!! it may help you

Comment: Camera Default of my Phone . It diplay portrait ok. I think it can set attribute when create camera.

Answer (score 1):

Manual for `setDisplayOrientation()` says:

> Set the clockwise rotation of **preview display** in degrees

and then

> This **does not** affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos.

You cannot rotate saved video stream, only preview.

Comment: I set mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); Camera had preview ok, Why result not the same camera view? Can you give me a example?

Comment: See edited answer. And why you did not read the documentation yet?

Answer (score 0):

here is a demo which work with both portrait and landscape see here

source
https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample

demo
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pikanji.camerapreviewsample&hl=en

Comment: Do you try record video yet? I test: Camera display portrait Ok, But file result (Video) not display portrait

Answer (score 0):

I know your issue,

Video use `Media Recorder` from `Camera`, so you need `rotate Media Recorder`. use below codes should be fixed your issue.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param mMediaRecorder
 * @return
 */
public static MediaRecorder rotateBackVideo(MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder) {
    /**
     * Define Orientation of video in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    switch (CustomCamera.current_orientation) {
        case 0:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            break;
        case 90:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
            break;
        case 180:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
            break;
        case 270:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);
            break;
    }

    return mMediaRecorder;
}
```

Should add before `prepare()` method :

```
// Step 5: Set the preview output
    /**
     * Define Orientation of image in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = Utils.rotateBackVideo(CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder);
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
```

Thank you